# Replacing value of column on a particular for different values

Tags: shell, awk

Hi I have a file with a long list of values for different things and I want to be able to increase the value of one thing to create a bunch of files for each value.

i.e my file looks like this:

test.dat

```
 5   500  Mruh
 6   100  Mrah 
 15  1.77 Mta
 .
 .
 .
```

and so on...
 I would ideally like to pick out the value of, say, 6 (which is 100) and increase it by 50 to then for each increase have a new file.
So the end product should be a new file looking like:

test_50.dat

```
5   500   Mruh
6   150   Mrah
15  1.77  Mta
```

I've tried using the awk command but ran into problems. Any help will be great.

Cheers!

Comment: Which problems did you run into? Show the code so we can try to give a guidance. Also, is then the `6` a parameter to be given and then always increase 50 (fixed)?

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk '$1==6 {sub($2,$2+50)}1' file >test_50.dat
cat test_50.dat     
5   500  Mruh
6   150  Mrah
15  1.77 Mta
```

Search for lines with `6` and then add `50` to column `#2`
I do use `sub` to preserve formatting like you see here:

```
awk '$1==6 {$2+=50}1' file >test_50.dat
cat test_50.dat
 5   500  Mruh
6 150 Mrah
 15  1.77 Mta
```

---

To get it to a file based on value `50`

```
awk '$1==6 {sub($2,$2+v)} {print $0 > "test_"v".dat"}' v=50 file
cat test_50.dat
 5   500  Mruh
 6   150  Mrah
 15  1.77 Mta
```

Comment: `sub()` doesn't keep format. and moreover, it is dangerous. because it does match with `regex`. think about the 2nd line is `6 6 Mrah`, your sub() will replace the 1st column. so the `+` solution is the right one. if one wants to have certain format, use `printf` etc later.

Comment: If you want to keep the formatting you could also use the `split()` function in Gnu Awk version 4. It has a fourth argument which is the separators between the fields..

Comment: @kent So how then keep the format using `awk` 3x (default on most ubuntu)?

Comment: @Jotne `printf` or external tool like column. `sub()` should not be used in this situation. E.g. `650 50 XXX` if `$1==650{sub(..)}` you got what I meant. your 2nd code block in answer is correct way.